# In ubuntu, which process is sending igmp packets?

Tags: ubuntu, router, igmp

My Ubuntu keeps sending out IGMP Query requests for following IPs: 239.255.255.255.253, 224.1.1.7 and 234.55.66.77. I figured this out from Wireshark. As per IGMP spec, I believe query requests are sent only by routers. So,

1. Why is my machine sending these packets (i.e. behaving like a router)?
2. Which process sends these packets? I checked there is no mrouted or XORP or Quagga installed.

Comment: Are those addresses in same subnet as your machine or public ip? Or belong to any websites your visiting? It looks like its not a router protocol but rather a wan multicast protocol. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you monitor the `netstat` to find out the 'culprit':

```
watch 'netstat -natp | grep 234.55.66.77'
```

There are some things you can check:

1. IGMP snooping feature is enabled:

   ```
   cat /sys/class/net/br0/bridge/multicast_snooping
   ```
2. you're using `corosync` in multicast mode

Comment: 2. I couldn't find corosync installed in my machine.

Comment: How about `netstat` and `multicast_snooping`?

Comment: Wanted to edit above comment to below but had 5 mins restriction.

watch didn't return anything. Moreover, -t gives only tcp connections right? IGMP info may not come in this command. 
1. AFAIK, IGMP snooping is only supposed to listen packets and not send them
2. I couldn't find corosync installed in my machine. (dpkg -l | grep corosync returned nothing)

Comment: multi_cast snooping is enabled.

Comment: `ps -ef | grep corosync`? Disable `multicast_snooping` to see if this problem go away.

Comment: No corosync processes running. Surprisingly, the problem seems to have vanished now. It is not sending query messages. Thanks a lot for your help.